# Multiple dispatch for methods of a class in Julia

Tags: julia, overloading, multiple-dispatch

My question is how can I overload certain method **within** a certain class in Julia?

In other words suppose I have a following definition of a class:

```
type Sometype
    prop::String

    setValue::Function

    # constructor
    function Sometype()
        this = new ()

        this.prop = ""

####### v1 #######
        this.setValue = function(v::Real)
            println("Scalar Version was Invoked!")
            # operations on scalar...
            # ...
        end

####### v2 #######
        this.setValue = function(v::Vector{Real})
            println("Vector Version was Invoked!")
            # operations on vector...
            # ...
        end

####### v3 #######
        this.setValue = function(v::Matrix{Real})
            println("Matrix Version was Invoked!")
            # operations on Matrix...
            # ...
        end

        return this
    end
end
```

So when I say in my main code:

```
st = Sometype()
st.setValue(val)
```

depending on whether `val` is a **scalar**, **vector** or **matrix** it would invoke the corresponding version of a `setvalue` method. Right now, with definition above, it overrides definitions of `setvalue` with the last one (matrix version in this case).

Comment: `setValue` is a variable with type `Function` and can be overridden just like other common variables. for now, it seems julia [doesn't support](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13259) multiple dispatch for `anonymous functions`.

Comment: The fact that it is overriding `setValue` is the problem here. I want to code it in such way that it will instead compile all versions of a `setValue` and one of those to get called appropriately to the type of the passed input `val`

Comment: you can use `generic function`, try to give those functions the same name e.g. `function foo(v::Real)`, `function foo(v::Vector{Real})`,`function foo(v::Matrix{Real})`. However, this is not julia-style, see @David's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This style of Object-Oriented Programming (OOP), in which the functions live inside objects, is not used in Julia.

Instead, in Julia we just define methods *outside* the object definition. E.g.:

```
type Sometype
    prop::String
end

Sometype(v::Real) = ...

function Sometype{T}(v::Vector{T})  # parametric type
    ....
end
```

Note that the first definition is an example of the short-hand way of defining simple functions on a single line, and the second example is for more complicated functions.

As pointed out by @GnimucKey, instead of `v::Vector{Real}`, you should use `v::Vector{T}` with the function parametrised by `T`. I have changed my answer accordingly. An argument specified as `v::Vector{Real}` will *never* match an argument, since it is impossible to create objects of the abstract type `Real`, and the invariance of types means that an object like `Vector{Float64}` is not a subtype of `Vector{Real}`.

Comment: i think `function Sometype{T<:Real}(v::Vector{T}) ... end` is better. cause `Vector{Int} <: Vector{Real}` will return a `false`, which is ​prone to getting some unexpected errors.

Comment: The behaviour of `<:` on parametric composite types @GnimucKey mentions is explained thoroughly [in the docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#parametric-composite-types)

Comment: @GnimucKey Yes, you're right, good point. I'll change my answer.